# getting battery level at android widget

Tags: android, android-widget, battery, receiver

I wrote a widget for Android and I'm trying to get the battery level.
I've tried using

```
Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

but I get the error:
"IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents"

Why? the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is a sticky intent and I don't register a receiver (null in the first parameter).

Any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: android bug? http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5111

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hackbod gave the solution at the comments:

" use getApplicationContext().registerReciever() "

Answer (score 3):

Ummmm...that feels like a bug. They must be doing the is-a-`BroadcastRecevier` check too soon. You might want to create a project that demonstrates the problem, then post that to [b.android.com](http://b.android.com).

In terms of a workaround:

Step #1: Create an `IntentService`

Step #2: In `onHandleIntent()`, do your actual widget update work, including getting the battery level

Step #3: Have `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider` just call `startService()` on your `IntentService`.

Comment: Or just use getApplicationContext().registerReciever().

Comment: @hackbod: In this case, `getApplicationContext()` would behave differently than the `Context` that `onReceive()` gets passed in?

Comment: @Ran: sorry, hers is a comment -- unless she rewrites it as an answer, there's no way for you to accept it.

Comment: @Ran: The "StackOverflow way" would be for you to write that into a new answer, or edit CommonsWare's answer (if you have permission) to include this info. Then you have an answer you can "accept".