# Get battery level only once using Android SDK

Tags: android, batterylevel

I've searched on the web and couldn't find the answer to my question. My problem is to get the battery level information only once, eg. calling the function `getBatteryLevel()`. There are only solutions which are implemented using `BroadcastReceiver`, but as I know it will be called every time on battery level's change event. Please, tell me how can I get that information only once?

Comment: Use a `BroadcastReceiver` and then once you get the value once just unregiester the receiver.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The [`Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) broadcast is what's known as a "sticky broadcast."  Because this is sticky, you can register for the broadcast with a null receiver which will only get the battery level **one** time when you call `registerReceiver`.

A function to get the battery level without receiving updates would look something like this:

```
public float getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
    if(level == -1 || scale == -1) {
        return 50.0f;
    }

    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f; 
}
```

More data can be pulled from this sticky broadcast.  Using the returned `batteryIntent` you can access other extras as outlined in the [`BatteryManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) class.

Comment: This method cannot now be called from withing a Receiver (e.g. a Widget). Do you know of any other way to get the battery level that can be done from within a Widget's onUpdate() method?

Comment: If you're doing this from a widget, you'll need to call `registerReceiver` like so: `getApplicationContext().registerReciever(...)` for it to work.

Comment: I have a context and can call it, but the call is not permitted from within a receiver, passing this or null as the first parameter "receiver". Log message is very explicit that you cannot call from within a receiver.

Comment: You can't use just any context, you need to use the context returned from `getApplicationContext()` to call `registerReceiver()` from within another receiver.  I have tried this and it works.  It is also the answer given in this question that is very similar to the one you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691579/getting-battery-level-at-android-widget

Comment: With ApplicationContext that worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Any special permission required for achieving this?

Comment: No permissions required according to the Android documentation.

Comment: This is the only way for a one-time power status query on startup. Using an arbitrary new intent won't work in that case. But subsequent power hotplug/unplug can be detected by a broadcast event.