# How create a permanent notification to show battery level

Tags: android, statusbar, android-notifications, batterylevel

I'm stuck in a creation of a notification..Just want display the battery level in the status bar(notifications bar)The notification has been permanent. This is part of code:

```
private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int  level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

              String[] status = {
                "Level: "+level
                 . . .
               };

             NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Level",System.currentTimeMillis());

             notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

             Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 

             PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);

             notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), +level+"%", penInt);

             notifi.notify(215,notification);


            }
};
```

Is it correct? Is there something else to add for example in the manifest? I don't have a specified class for the notification so i wrote in this way this line: `Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);` but i don't know if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
```

More information here :

[Get battery level only once using Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746709/get-battery-level-only-once-using-android-sdk)

Comment: ok it works thanks. One thing, Now here `Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,+level+"%",System.currentTimeMillis())` i want display only the level and not the icon. Actually it show me only the icon battery in the status bar. Is there a way to delete it?