# How to get the value of battery percentage to an int value

Tags: android

I want to receive the battery info to a text type and the value of "level" is not accessible outside the broadcast receiver. How to access the value of level out side the broadcast receiver in the code to use it in oncreate method

```
    public BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "");


    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get battery level only once using Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746709/get-battery-level-only-once-using-android-sdk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get battery level and state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Get [battery level only once using Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746709/get-battery-level-only-once-using-android-sdk) You can use the following code:

```
 Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
 int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your oncreate method:

Declare your textview in oncreate

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

And implement receiver within that activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                      Log.e("ebre", level+"**");
            batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "");
                    }
                  };
```

**EDIT**

Wherever you want to activate receiver just used this to call the receiver

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

If you want the battery percentage then declare it in the activity and use the value.

Comment: what if i also have to use that value outside the oncreate method

Comment: also in which variavle will i receive the int value outside the broadcast receiver

Comment: Wherever you want just use this to activate the receiver
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));